# Spring MockMvc and async controller's HTTP status code

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test, mockmvc

How do i validate/test the 500 internal server error in MockMvc, when my controller is of **Async servlet nature**?

I am writing unit test cases for my REST endpoint as part of a test cases i need to validate that the server sends 500 internal error as http code and with appropriate error message.

Here is my spring boot based app:
(all imports are omitted for better readability)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{name}", 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private DeferredResult<String> greetByJson(@PathVariable("name") final String name){
        DeferredResult<String> dResult = new DeferredResult<String>();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    dResult.setErrorResult(new RuntimeException("Boom!!! time for Internal server error"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        return dResult;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
}
```

Here is my MovkMvc JUnit test cases:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AppTest {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new App())
            .build();

    @Test
    public void testAsyncInternalServerError() {
        try {
            MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/user/naveen").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                    .andReturn();

            System.out.println("Http Response Content = " + mvcResult.getAsyncResult());
            System.out.println("Http Response Status Code = " + mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the console prints:

```
2015-08-08 18:11:51.494  INFO 10224 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@a82c5f1: startup date [Sat Aug 08 18:11:51 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-08 18:11:51.526  INFO 10224 --- [           main] o.e.j.i.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner    : Started RemoteTestRunner in 0.258 seconds (JVM running for 1.131)
Http Response Content = java.lang.RuntimeException: Boom!!! time for Internal server error
Http Response Status Code = 200
2015-08-08 18:11:56.584  INFO 10224 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@a82c5f1: startup date [Sat Aug 08 18:11:51 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

From the above log its evident that MockMvc returns http status code as 200 not 500. The error message is just fine.

Where as when i invoke the end point using Chrome postman, i see 500 internal server error as attached in the image[image]

Comment: You should really accept @mzc 's answer. :)

Answer (score 14):

You must perform async dispatch and test the status afterwards:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/your/endpoint"))
            .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
            .andExpect(request().asyncResult(notNullValue()))
            .andReturn();

    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
            .andReturn();

}
```

Comment: Hi, To me the assertion fails for this line: `.andExpect(request().asyncStarted())` Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Custom `perform` helper method that handles both sync and async request:

```
ResultActions perform(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(builder);
    if (resultActions.andReturn().getRequest().isAsyncStarted()) {
      return mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(resultActions
          .andExpect(request().asyncResult(anything()))
          .andReturn()));
    } else {
      return resultActions;
    }
}
```

[Longer answer with example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685479/1227867)

Answer (score 0):

Following is working example(Groovy Spock specification), with a method `asyncPerform(builder)`

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.notNullValue
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*

@ContextConfiguration(classes = [MyConfig])
@WebAppConfiguration
class MyControllerComponentSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

    MockMvc endpoint

    def setup() {
        endpoint = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build()
    }

    ResultActions asyncPerform(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder) throws Exception {
         ResultActions resultActions = endpoint.perform(builder);
         asyncDispatch(resultActions.andExpect(request()
                        .asyncResult(notNullValue()))
                        .andReturn()));
     }

    def "accepts valid request and responds with 200 status code and response body"() {
        when:
        def response = asyncPerform(post("/my_async_endpoint")
            .content("""{"correlationID": "fe5d1699-20e3-4502-bf51-b947e6b9e51a"}""")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
            .andDo(print())

        then:
        response.andExpect(status().is(200))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("body.correlationID").value("fe5d1699-20e3-4502-bf51-b947e6b9e51a"))

    }
}
```